# Change a while loop to foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm about to change a code to "WordPress-customized code" (using $wpdb). And with `$wpdb->get_results()` I get an array that need to be outputted with a foreach loop. But the problem is that my current while-loop has a "$initial_hidden statement" in it that I don't know how to do with the new foreach.

Here is my current code:

```
while (($initial_hidden == true) || ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))) {

...

}
```

So, how do I get the "initial hidden" to this:

```
foreach ($q as $r) {

...

}
```

Comment: Okay, "WordPress-code". I meant using $wpdb...

Comment: for($i = 0; (i<sizeof($q)) || ($initial_hidden == true) ; i++)
    {
        # code ...
    }

Comment: Marcin Orlowski: It doesn't have to be foreach. But I have to be able to loop the output from get_results() in any way. And since I can't do it with while, I just thought of foreach. I guess Hienz method work. And I then use $q[$i] to output data from the array?

Comment: Yea, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

> So, how do I get the "initial hidden" to this

You can abort `foreach` with regular `break;` so simply add `if()` in loop body and `break` when condition is met.

```
foreach($q as $r) {
     ...

   if ($initial_hidden) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this line of code: $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q); if(($initial_hidden) || (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)) { foreach($r as $key => $value) { //result } }

Answer (score -1):

You can also have foreach inside the while loop

```
while (($initial_hidden == true) || !empty(mysql_fetch_assoc($q))) {
foreach($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
}
...

}
```

Comment: But the thing with the initial_hidden is to process everything in the iteration even if the array is empty. That's not working with your method.

Comment: you can use `!empty` in while for that